# Appium multiple drivers

Tags: java, selenium, testng, appium

I'm currently working on mobile automation with Appium. The goal is to run the same test on different devices at the same time. My question is how to do efficiently. I have searched a lot for a solution, but most of the questions are how to run multiple devices with selenium grid. I am one step further.

I want to create a setup class that creates a driver that is later used with the tests. But if I have multiple devices at the same time I would have to have multiple drivers as well.

I was thinking I could create an array/list of all the drivers, pass that to the test and get it executed for each driver. Though it wouldn't be in parallel but sequentially, and that's not what I am aiming for.
Duplicating the test/code is also not the way to go.

How to signal that I have more drivers and I want to execute one instance of the test for each driver ?
The code is only to visualize what I mean.

```
@BeforeTest
class setup
   List<AndroidDriver> driverList
   driverList.Add(driver1)
   driverList.Add(driver2)

class Test extends setup
@Test
   for (AndroidDriver driver : setup.driverList)
      //TEST
```